# Xampp MySQL Crashed and doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

I was coding with a working Apache and MySQL Xampp Server.

While coding suddenly the whole project killed his self.. 80% of the functions just crashed and worked wrong. No Error messages, no console messages. Everything seemed working nice, but the most functions just did the wrong.

Then suddenly.. I got error messages, that it can't connect to the MySQL Database. I was shocked and just reboot my PC.

After a reboot, I started Xampp, startet Apache and MySQL. No error messages, the Background of the Modulname changed to "Green (Successfully started)".

Than I started my browser and changed the URL to my project... same error message, can't connect to the MySQL Database.

I went to localhost/phpmyadmin.

In the PhpMyAdmin I tryed to log in and get following error message:

```
"#1045 Die Anmeldung am MySQL-Server ist fehlgeschlagen" -> "#1045 Login to the MySQL-Server failed"
```

I tried following in the command line

```
    mysql -u root -password PASSWORD

    mysql -u root -p PASSWORD

    mysql -u root
```

Nothing of them worked. Following error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I also downloaded a mysqlreset.bat which does a SQL Update Query and set a new root password. No - it didn't work.

I don't know what happened.

Anyone know this error? I am searching for a solution, but need to quickly get back to work. Meanwhile I will still search around and will response if I found a solution.

Comment: You make it sound as if someone changed the password on your database. Are any of your colleagues doing maintenance on the server?

Comment: Be careful when "downloading a `mysqlreset.bat`" - make sure you are happy it works and is safe before you use such a thing. You don't need that sort of thing anyway - you can restart MySQL in no-password mode, reset the password, and then restart normally.

Comment: "most functions just did the wrong [thing]" - sounds like the database password problem, but your functions are failing silently rather than reporting that the database connection has failed.

Comment: 1. Comment: I have another mate, but he is doing something else and don't have the knowledge to do something wrong.

Comment: 2. Comment: I opened the `.bat` inside a texteditor and it was safe. I will try to restart MySQL in no-password mode and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few re-installs, I de-installed Xampp from the systems menu, deleted the C:/xampp/ directory and installed xampp again. ( Of course I did backups of my C:/xampp/data and C:/xampp/htdocs )

Everything works now perfect. I don't know what the hell gone wrong and I hope it never happens again.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

if it is not the case that Halcyon say. this mean you computer was shutdown anormaly. for the version xampp in developpment mode this appear currently in mysql and the problem is in :
a big error of save of database.

you can try to go to the path :
..bin\database\mysql-5.6.11\data\

and restore with wokbench data or any soft in the files: .frm, .myd, .myi

next time think to save a backup of informations in .sql

after restore delete xampp and install another like :uwamp

hope this be helpfull

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and give report.